# R How to calculate a proportion of some value by column and by row in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

Sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(c('ab','cd','..'),c('ab','..','ab'),c('..','cd','cd'))
```

I'm trying to get the proportion of ab's for each column and row, but ignoring ..'s from the total in the numerator and denominator.

Proportion of ab's = total number of ab's excluding ../ number of any symbol except ..

For example for column 1 (values are ab,cd,and ..), the proportion of ab's is 0.5

What I have so far:

```
fun <- function(x) {
    length(which(x == 'ab'))/length(which(x != '..'))
}
byColumn<- sapply(df[,1:ncol(df)],fun)
byRow <- sapply(df[1:nrow(df),],fun)
```

Expected result:

```
byColumn <- c(0.5,1.0,0.0)
byRow <- c(1.0,0.0,0.5)
```

Actual result:

```
byColumn <- c(0.5,1.0,0.0)
byRow <- c(0.5,1.0,0.0)
```

But byRow isn't working... it seems to be the same output as byColumn?

Comment: I would just go with `colSums(df == "ab")/colSums(df != "..")` and `rowSums(df == "ab")/rowSums(df != "..")`

Comment: Or `byRow <- apply(df, 1, fun)` & `byCol <- apply(df, 2, fun)`.

Comment: `sapply` takes a `list`. Try `unlist(df[1:nrow(df),])` & `unlist(df[,1:ncol(df)])` to gain a little more understanding of what's happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define the function as follows (you can play around with the settings)

```
Propfunc <- function(x, dim = "col", equal = "ab", ignore = ".."){
  if(dim == "col") return(unname(colSums(x == equal)/colSums(x != ignore)))
  if(dim == "row") return(rowSums(x == equal)/rowSums(x != ignore))
  else stop("Unknown dim")
}

Propfunc(df)
## [1] 0.5 1.0 0.0
Propfunc(df, dim = "row")
## [1] 1.0 0.0 0.5
Propfunc(df, dim = "blabla")
## Error in Propfunc(df, dim = "blabla") : Unknown dim
```

Comment: Does `Propfunc` stand for "Proper function"?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your function. Then `byRow`you use the same code that is working `byColumn` but transposing the data frame:

```
byColumn <- sapply(df[, 1:ncol(df)], fun)
byRow <- sapply(as.data.frame(t(df))[, 1:ncol(df)], fun)
```

Output:

```
# By column
col1 col2 col3 
0.5  1.0  0.0 
# By row
 V1  V2  V3 
1.0 0.0 0.5
```